# Python: Trying to loop through a string to find matching characters

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create a simple "guess the word" game in Python. My output is something like:

```
String: _____ _____
Guess a word: 'e'

String:_e__o __e_e
Guess a word: 'h'

(and so on)

String: hello there
```

I have a function to do this, and within this function I have this code:

```
def guessing(word):
    count = 0
    blanks = "_" * len(word)
    letters_used = "" #empty string 

    while count<len(word):
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter:")
        blanks = list(blanks)
        #Checks if guesses are valid
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Please guess only one letter at a time."
        elif guess not in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "):
            print "Please only guess letters!"

        #Checks if guess is found in word
        if guess in word and guess not in letters_used:
            x = word.index(guess)
            for x in blanks:
                blanks[x] = guess
            letters_used += guess 
            print ("".join(blanks))
            print "Number of misses remaining:", len(word)-counter
            print "There are", str(word.count(guess)) + str(guess)
```

`guess` is the raw input I get from the user for a guess, and `letters_used` is just a collection of guesses that the user has already input. What I'm trying to do is loop through blanks based on the `word.index(guess)`. Unfortunately, this returns:

```
Guess a letter: e
e___
Yes, there are 1e
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `x`? Please provide the full working reproducible code.

Comment: @Anmol Singh Jaggi sorry about that. Inserted full code

Answer (score 2):

Your code was almost correct. There were few mistakes which I have corrected:

```
def find_all(needle, haystack):
    """
    Finds all occurances of the string `needle` in the string `haystack`
    To be invoked like this - `list(find_all('l', 'hello'))` => #[2, 3]
    """
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += 1


def guessing(word):
    letters_uncovered_count = 0
    blanks = "_" * len(word)
    blanks = list(blanks)
    letters_used = ""

    while letters_uncovered_count < len(word):
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter:")

        #Checks if guesses are valid
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Please guess only one letter at a time."
        elif guess not in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
            print "Please only guess letters!"

        if guess in letters_used:
          print("This character has already been guessed correctly before!")
          continue

        #Checks if guess is found in word
        if guess in word:
            guess_positions = list(find_all(guess, word))
            for guess_position in guess_positions:
                blanks[x] = guess
                letters_uncovered_count += 1
            letters_used += guess 
            print ("".join(blanks))
            print "Number of misses remaining:", len(word)-letters_uncovered_count
            print "There are", str(word.count(guess)) + str(guess)
        else:
          print("Wrong guess! Try again!")
```